# CRM 2011 Reports timeout

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I am having a problem with some CRM Reports as they are not being rendered with the error

Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.DataExtensionShim.Common.ReportExecutionException: The fetch data set query timed out after 307.9435095 seconds. Increase the query timeout, and try again.

I dont know where to change that limit , but I changed the following limits in both CRM Application servers.
OLEDBTimeout , ExtendedTimeout , NormalTimeout

Do not time out ( through ReportManager for the whole report manager and for the report itself)

executed SessionTimeout.rss script against the report manager

executiontime and maxrequestlength in web.config for CRM website

But I am still getting the error as I cant optimize the query , the report is huge and takes 5 minutes of processing but it keeps showing an error after exactly 319 seconds.

This problem applies to CRM out of the box reports and also for reports developed in BIDS

Reports works fine if the data is not huge.

Answer (score 0):

[Joe CRM](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2013/06/28/timeouts-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/) at Power Objects has a little guide that might help. 
Hope that helps.